# ANTLR2 error reporting

Tags: java, antlr, antlr2

When the parser/lexer encounters an error,it prints it to the `console` and recovers so that the parsing can happen. For the end-user, it is an API call, and I would like to inform him about the parse error, so that he can rectify. Currently, I am only able to detect that an error has occurred.

My question: How do I propogate the error message to the end-user? I am not able to get the error message as this is handled in the ANTLR generated parser/lexer file.

Grammar generated for Java.

EDIT 1: Grammar was written sometime back. So, need the solution in ANTLR2 only.

EDIT 2: I found that if we set `defaultErrorHandler=false;`, then the default error handlers are not generated in the lexer/parser and we can catch these exceptions directly in the handling code.

Comment: ANTLR 2? Are you sure you want to use such an old release?

Comment: It had been written sometime back. Need significant effort to port it. So, yes, have to find the solution in ANTLR2